# Is it possible to say the time in 24 hour?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-requests

Is it possible to say the time in 24 hour in Esperanto, like 22:34?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I think it is quite common to use the 24-hour system in Esperanto. I think your example would be pronounced:

> Estas la dudek-dua kaj tridek kvar.

[PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/nombroj/horoj.html) has an article about telling the time. According to to that, it is normal to say the minutes by just saying *kaj* and then the number of minutes. I guess Bertilow is suggesting to avoid phrases like “it’s half ten” because for different languages similar phrases to that can mean either 9:30 or 10:30. In that case you can just say “… kaj tridek” and there is no problem if you want to be extra precise and say “… kaj tridek kvar”.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is. When I was in France (in the castle [Grésillon](http://gresillon.org/?lang=eo)) this was actually done. They would, for instance, announce that *tagmanĝo estos je la dek-tria* and *la ekskurso komenciĝos je la dek-kvina*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In fact, the 24 hour system is much more common than the 12 hour system in Esperanto because it's clearer.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it's very possible. Note however that rather than 22:30, it's likely to see it written 22h30.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/875)

Comment: The question was whether it is possible to say the time in 24 hour in Esperanto, like 22:34. In addition to the clarifications already given, it's often written with an "h" in it. I will clarify my answer.

Comment: I would say the "h" thing is out of topic. Here is a question to which this would fit: http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/2702/how-do-you-format-the-hour-in-esperanto ; For the other part "Yes, it's very possible" you don't add anything compared to the previous answers. A comment to the question or to an already made answer would have been more suited.

Comment: The question was whether it is possible to say the time like 22:33. The difference between 22:33 and 22h33 is absolutely relevant.